# Mysql query with low performance

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

On a table with big data I need to run the following query:

```
SELECT `messages_outbox`.* 
FROM `messages_outbox` 
WHERE (valid = 'notconfirm' and state != 'no_rcpt') 
ORDER BY `time_send` asc LIMIT 100
```

It's very slow and making an index on the 3 fields didn't solve the problem. I have the following index on the table:

```
create index `valid_state_time-send`
    on messages_outbox (state, valid, time_send);
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please share the execution plan of your query, and more details about the table

Comment: Please don't write things like _"table with big data"_ as everyone has their own idea of what it means. If you wish to emphasise size, be more explicit - _"3.7 billion rows with average row length ### bytes"_. Similarly for _"very slow"_, is this 0.1s or 30s? With `state` as the first column in the index and `state != 'no_rcpt'`, no index will be used. Please add details requested by Nico, and set of values for `state` and more context would be helpful too.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since `!=` is not easily optimizable, you may as well have only

```
(valid, time_send)
```

If there is only one other value for `state`, then change the `WHERE`; then the 3-column index will be optimal.